# macOs scientific calculator with history

Tags: macos, calculator

The company I work for, gave me a MacBookPro with M1 chip, but I'm still new to Mac OS.

Could you please recommend/suggest me a free scientific calculator with history that can be installed on a company-controlled notebook OR at least something the IT department would not make too much fuss?

I've had a look at [PCalc](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/5870/pcalc) and [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/downloads), which were suggested in this [article](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/109/is-there-a-scientific-calculator-app-that-runs-on-os-x), but I want something simpler that can be installed for free and not need internet connection ... something like the windows 10 calculator

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's not something I've ever really used myself, so I don't know its intimate details, but did you know you can swap the simple built-in calculator to Scientific [or Programmer] mode & add a paper tape emulation for history…

[image]

You can even save the 'paper tape' if you need.

Comment: Thank you! That's handy. But how do you keep on tape an operation with functions? E.g. you want to compute sine of 30 degrees; you click [pi][/][6][sin] and the calculator shows you 0.5 (if working with radians) but the tape shows you only pi/6

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how it works. It's not a mode I've ever used.